# What does status R mean regarding trail permits on the Mt Whitney lottery calendar?

Tags: hiking, california

I lost out on the Mt Whitney lottery--dates I was looking for now say R--does that mean I am out of luck or will some slots be available later, like in the April 1 access date?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it means that you are out of luck for that day.

> After the Mt Whitney Lottery, any remaining dates may be reserved on the website www.recreation.gov beginning at 10:00am Eastern Time on April 1st. **When searching for an available date, the letter "R" on the reservation calendar indicates that date is full.** Reductions in group size and canceled space will be released for web reservations at a random time within 24 hours of cancelation. A reservation is not final until you have successfully completed checking out the shopping cart and paid reservation fees in full.

[Source](https://www.fs.usda.gov/detail/inyo/passes-permits/recreation/?cid=stelprdb5150055)

The full legend of what the letters stand for on the calander is,

> - A: Available for online reservation (click to book entry date)
> - a: Available for online reservation with earlier arrival date
> - L: Accepting Lottery Application (click to apply for the lottery)
> - W: Available at the Facility
> - R: Reserved
> - C: Closed
> - X: Not available
> - N: Not available

[Source](https://www.recreation.gov/permits//r/entranceDetails.do?arvdate=06/06/2018&contractCode=NRSO&parkId=72201&entranceId=315840&pGroupSize=1)